# How to customize table-view in iphone?

Tags: iphone

HA ii everybody,i want to customize the table-view cell like the image shown below,that is cells are not separated by one-by one.I strongly believe that this could not be possible but if i got a solution for this it will be a great great help for me.Now i show different verses of bible in a cell like the ordinary table-view cells.But i want to do by this way as shown in the image.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCell can be subclassed. Just create your own custom Cells that have greater height than needed to just hold the text. This extra height will act as a separator before the next cell.

Comment: there's a lot information from apple here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use cells, they're just *paragraphs* of text. So just separate your paragraphs with newlines, ie "\n\n"

Comment: ,u saind the right thing sir,but i need to highlight those verses,my verses are from sqlite,i know highliting is possible only in webview with richtext or html by coding javascript,but i want to do it in tableview cell.

Comment: It would have been useful to mention that requirement in the question!

Comment: when the user tap the verse number it will highlight the verse and shows a popover with some buttons.now i done it with tableviewcell,it works fine,but i want this type of view.thats the problem,if i can costomize the cell like this its very helpful